# Notation of a sum

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I just have a question about the notation of sums. So I want to make a sum which goes from $1$ to $n$, but doesnt include $i$. This can be done as two sums like this:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j +\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}x_j$$

Can I write this as one sum like the following: (or is there another way)
$$\sum_{i\neq j}^n x_j$$

Comment: Use $\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)-x_i$  For more complicated things, we use $\sum_{k\in A}x_k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is $$\sum_{i \in \{ 1,2,\ldots,n\} \setminus \{j\}} x_i.$$ This is totally clear but somehow cumbersome. Sometimes I have seen $$\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ i \neq j}}^n x_i,$$ which is even worse...

Comment: Why is it (the last notation) worse? It's a relatively easy notation and still seems clear to me? I've seen this notation quite often.

Comment: I prefer the first, as you can get more complicated with it.  @StackTD It just feels improper I guess if you don't use it often.  And how would you have an exclusion of multiple values from the sum?  very cumbersome IMO

Comment: Thanks, but is the notation $\sum_{i\neq j}^n x_j$ wrong, or just bad/messy?

Comment: @SimpleArt: it's a handy notation for excluding one value, but that happens to be something you come across a lot...

Comment: @C.Klum: when is a notation 'wrong'? If 'we' agree to use it and we give a meaning to it, then... I agree notations are preferably clear and unambiguous, but to be useful they're also preferably simple and short.

Comment: @C.Klum If I am not mistaken in your case it should be $j\neq i$ as you're working with $x_j$.

Comment: @C.Klum How does your notation explain that you want to start at $i=1$?  I could misinterpret that part from your notation.